# How to create package object which will be available to all the inner packages in scala?

Tags: scala, package

I have package structure like this.

In file A/B/package.scala

```
package A
package object B {
  def foo = "Hello world"
}
```

In file A/B/xyz.scala

```
package A.B
object bar {
  def baz() {
    println(foo())
  }
}
```

This won't throw error. It will work as expected. But if I try to use like:

In file A/B/C/biz.scala

```
package A.B.C
object biz {
  def baz() {
    println(foo())
  }
}
```

It will throw error as foo is not in the scope of inner package. I need to have global access to foo(). How can I achieve it?

One way is to import A.B like `import A.B._`.

But it will import all the classes in A.B package which I don't want to do.
Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Just note that your file structure doesn't influence scala scopes and packages. Scala compiler doesn't care if you declare `package F` in the file `A/B/xyz.scala`.

Comment: Sorry. It is a typo. It was supposed to be package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best fit is `import A.B.foo` (and other specific methods you need). You can also make `foo` available in a non-package object and import all of its methods. Of course, you can *also* have them in the package object:

```
package A.B

abstract class ABMethods { def foo = ... }


package A

package object B extends ABMethods { ... }


package A.B

object Foo extends ABMethods { ... }
```

But there is no way to have all of package object methods available without all classes of `A.B`.